# memory pool for objects with container of object pointers

Tags: c++

I have an object defined as,

```
class X
{
    string name;
    map<string,string> value;
    vector<X*> ptrs;
public:
    X(const char a* ="", const char* b ="") 
    {
        value[a]=b;
    }
    ~X()
    {
        for( i = 0; i< ptrs.size();i++)
            delete ptr[i];
    }
};

int main()
{
    while( j++ < 200)
    {
        X* p = new X;
        while( i++ < 100)
        {
            X* y = new X("one","first");
            p.add(y);
        }
        delete p;
    }
}
```

Multiple allocations of `X` and `ptr` are being made.

How do i re-use the memory in such cases?
I want to avoid multiple new and delete calls, leading to high VM usage.

Comment: Give us some example code, right now your question is unclear.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please [clarify](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49133743/edit).

Comment: class X
{
    string name;
    map<string,string> value;
    vector<X*> ptrs;
public:
    ~X() {   for( i = 0; i< ptrs.size();i++)
                 delete ptr[i];
            }
};
int main()
{
    X* p = new X
    X.add(p);

Comment: @Rustic I recommend that new code and new information be appended directly to the question. See the `edit` button just after the question the question, before the comments, on the left side.

Comment: class X
{

    string name;

    map<string,string> value;

    vector<X*> ptrs;

public:

     X(const char a* ="", const char* b ="")

    {
          value[a]=b;
    }

    ~X() {   for( i = 0; i< ptrs.size();i++)
                 delete ptr[i];
            }
};

int main()
{

    while( j++ < 200) {

        X* p = new X;

        while( i++ < 100){

              X* y = new X("one","first");

              p.add(y);

         }

         delete p;
    }  
}

Comment: Edit it in your question, not in the comments.

Comment: A simple approach would be to just replace each call to `delete` with code that adds the no-longer-in-use object to some sort of recycling-bin-container (e.g. a std::vector) instead.  Then instead of calling `new` to get a new object, first see if that container is non-empty; if so, call pop_back() on it to get a recycled object to use; OTOH if it is empty, fall back to calling `new` to get a fresh object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can by using placement new

```
// Allocate initial memory
X *arr = new X[number_of_elems];

for (size_t i = 0; i < number_of_elems; i++) {
  new (arr + i) X();  // Create objects in place
}

// Destroy object without deleting
arr[index].~X();

// create on that space again
new (arr + index) X();
```

EDIT: 
Reading your question again you want to use a container, in that case you should use a custom allocator that uses a memory pool container. In that case the allocator will call that container to give memory to the STL container as needed, while the memory pool will do just a big alloc and give pointers of memory as needed (it could be for example increasing a pointer, but you might get into fragmentation problems if you want to remove objects from different points of your vector)